# configuring jboss to avoid external schema fetches

Tags: java, xml, jpa, jboss

All,

In our "higher" environments, we aren't allowed access to the world to fetch resources.  Our JBoss application uses JPA, and our logs show that we are trying to fetch the persistence_2_0.xsd from the outside world, and failing due to firewall restrictions.

How can I teach jboss to intercept requests for the schema file, and provide a locally managed file instead?

While I'm asking in the context of the persistence schema, there are other services we use that have similar problems.  In some of these cases, the schema includes other external resources, and we would like to be able to intercept the subsequent calls to serve instead locally managed resources.

For instance, if one of our XML files has:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
```

How can I intercept

```
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd
```

and provide

```
/opt/local/schemas/persistence_2_0.xsd
```

without going to the outside world?

Here's the error in our log:

```
10.xx.xx.xxx, remoteHostname=10.xx.xx.xxx, remotePort=0, scheme=http, requestServerName=null, requestServerPort=0, headerFields=null, audit=null]] 2013-03-20 18:43:22,679 WARN  [org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader] [http-name%2F10.yyy.yy.yy-8080-1] [request_httpUniqueId=(null)] Warning parsing XML: XML InputStream(4) schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect your JPA implementation and your JavaEE container to be perfectly capable of having their own local versions of those XSDs and resolve against those (so cut out any remote accesses). [DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2), for example, does just that using the XSD that is in one of its jars.

Comment: You might expect that.  I know I did until I started seeing the errors in my log.

Comment: suggest you tag your question as Hibernate then, since (some) other JPA providers handle that situation